# @OneToOne JPA Hibernate Exception - could not resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate

I new in Hibernate, I tried do a relationship one to one but show this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Grupos of: com.seguridad.modelos.Empleados [ from com.seguridad.modelos.Empleados e left join e.Grupos g where e.idJefe=:supervisor order by nombre]
```

I have two tables: Empleados and Grupos like this:

> Table Empleoyess:
>
> > idEmpleado (key) | nombre | aPat | aMat | grupo
>
> Table Grupos
>
> > id (key) | nombre | fecha |

The relation bewteen in Empleados(Empleoyess) and Grupos(Groups) is Empleados.grupo = Grupos.id

## Empleoyess.java

```
 @Entity()
 @Table(name="empleados")
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)

 public class Empleados implements Serializable {

    private String nombre;
    private String aPat;
    private String aMat;
    @Column(name="grupo")
    private Integer idGrupo; 

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Grupos grupos;

    //GETTER AND SETTERS
    }
```

## Grupos.java

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="grupos")

public class Grupos implements Serializable {
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nombre;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fecha;

//GETTER AND SETTERS
}
```

This is my query

> from com.seguridad.modelos.Empleados e left join e.Grupos g where e.idJefe = 5

and show the error before , but if I try :

> from Empleados e, Grupos g where e. idJefe=5 and e.idGrupo=g.id order by e.nombre

is sucessful, I can´t understand where is the error, others posts tell about syntax, but I believe my syntax is correct

Regards and thanks!

Comment: You've posted  the same query in the last part.

Comment: what is the difference between 1st and second query

Comment: You are mapping twice the `Grupos`  relationship in `Empleados` class: one with the `@OneToOne` relationship and another with the `idGrupo` instance variable. Remove the second one, you don't need it, and check the first one so that you are sure it is correct for your mapping.

Comment: sorry, my firts query is: from Empleados e left join e.Grupos g where e.idJefe=5 get all users with or with out group

Comment: I tried delete idGrupo and the result is the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field is named `grupos`, not `Grupos`. Case matters.